# How to run tests in a Multi Module Springboot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am currently experimenting with Multi Modules for Springboot and I would to know what are the good or best practices when running tests within different modules that do not contain `@SpringBootApplication` annotation but have structures or beans like `@RestController` without errors such as:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.mavenmultimodule.controllers.AdditionController required a bean of type 'com.example.mavenmultimodule.services.SumService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.mavenmultimodule.services.SumService' in your configuration.
```

Failed test:

```java
package com.example.mavenmultimodule.controllers;

imports...

@SpringBootTest(classes = AdditionController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class AdditionControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private SumService sumService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn5() throws Exception {
        SumModel s = new SumModel();
        s.setN1(2.0);
        s.setN2(3.0);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(s);

        when(sumService.sum(s)).thenReturn(5.0);

        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/sum")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(json)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        assertEquals(5, result.getResponse());
    }

}
```

I have the following structure:

```
Parent
- pom.xml
- addition
  - pom.xml
  - src
    - main
    - test
- subtraction
  - pom.xml
  - src
    - main
    - test
- application
  - pom.xml
  - src
    - main
    - test
```

Where application/src/main/MavenMultiModuleApplication contains the following code:

```java
    package com.example.mavenmultimodule;
    
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.mavenmultimodule")
    public class MavenMultiModuleApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(MavenMultiModuleApplication.class, args);
        }
    
    }
```

The parent pom file contains the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenmultimodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mavenmultimodule</name>
    <description>mavenmultimodule</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>addition</module>
        <module>subtraction</module>
        <module>application</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The application pom file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Parent for the dependencies -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Custom dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>addition</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>subtraction</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And both addition and subtraction module contain pom contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Parent for the dependencies -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>subtraction</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Link to the repository in question on Github:
https://github.com/filipe-costa/maven-multi-module

Link to the failing test:
https://github.com/filipe-costa/maven-multi-module/blob/main/addition/src/test/java/com/example/mavenmultimodule/controllers/AdditionControllerTest.java

Comment: You are using the wrong annotation, you want `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;` not `@Mock`

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz, thanks a lot! I will post my answer shortly!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out thanks to Igor.

I not only had to add `@MockBean` to the service being mocked but also the following annotations to the testing class `@WebMvcTest(controllers = AdditionController.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration(classes = AdditionController.class)`.

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AdditionController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AdditionController.class)
class AdditionControllerTest {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @MockBean
    private SumService sumService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturn5() throws Exception {
        Double expectedValue = 5.0;
        SumModel s = new SumModel();
        s.setN1(2.0);
        s.setN2(3.0);

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(s);

        given(this.sumService.sum(any())).willReturn(expectedValue);

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/sum")
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .content(json)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(expectedValue.toString()));
    }
}
```

I am still unsure if it is a good practice to not have a SpringBootApplication annotated class in the addition module.

It works for what I needed to understand, I hope this might help others as well.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you'd need the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation in my experience just `@WebMvcTest` does the job. SpringBootTest and WebMvcTest are slightly different things, this link may help clarify: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications